# Gerando thumbnails através do FileReader

Tags: javascript, html5

Quero gerar thumbnails de imagens que o usuário seleciona. O meu problema é que sempre uma das imagens gera 3 thumbnails

Demo aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/gTLXp/

Comment: *No meu caso gerou quatro, ganho um bônus por isso?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você não deve usar `for .. in` para iterar sobre arrays (ou *array-likes*). Ele é usado para iterar sobre as propriedades de um objeto. Como seu `FileList` tem três propriedades (`"0"`, `"length"` e `"item"`) o código vai executar três vezes.

Substitua por um `for` comum:

```
for (var key = 0 ; key < files.length ; key++)
```

[Exemplo atualizado](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/gTLXp/2/).

Comment: Curiosamente resolver o problema é mais fácil ainda usando ES6: http://jsfiddle.net/PqppL/

Comment: Achei que as linhas 14,15 e 16 do exemplo pudessem cuidar disso, mas percebi agora que mesmo quando faço 'files.item("qualquer coisa")' uma imagem é retornada.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues Verdade. Você sabe o quão bem suportado ES6 é nos browsers atuais? Não achei nenhuma informação no caniuse.com

Comment: Não estou falando de suporte atual, mas que o ES6 resolve o problema do `for in` com arrays tão facilmente. Suporte? Acho que só o Firefox.

Comment: @LucasMarçalDosSantos estranho... deve ser um bug. A documentação de [`FileList.item`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList#item%28%29) pede claramente um índice numérico. Aliás, vou atualizar minha resposta, pois ela só funciona por causa desse bug :P

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues Seu exemplo funcionou perfeitamente no Chrome.

Comment: Você deve estar com algum flag ligado no seu Chrome, pois pra mim dá erro de sintaxe até no Canary.

Comment: @bfavaretto ops, falha minha. De fato ele dá erro de sintaxe comigo também (devo ter olhado pro código de um fiddle, mas executado o de outro)

Comment: @bfavaretto Acompanho o blog de atualizações do Chrome mesmo usando Firefox, esperando para o dia que eles suportarão ES6, hifenação e outras coisas. Nem NodeJS suporta isso, tenho que ficar usando as AltJS para coisas simples como `.map((el)=>el[1])`.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é o uso do `for (... in ...)`, que lê também as propriedades do array de files, tal como `length`. Ou seja, você está adicionando uma imagem quando a propriedade length é iterada!

**EDIT** Uma ajuda para gerar o thumb:

Só para suplementar a resposta, você pode redimensionar o elemento `img` de forma a manter as proporções da imagem original, definindo o seguinte estilo para ela:

```
max-width: 20px; /* qualquer largura máxima desejada */
width: auto;
height: auto;
```